# `@JsonRootName` ignored when used with POJONode

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

While working on legacy code, I have created a wrapper class which extends `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.POJONode` (I cannot avoid this).

Despite I have annotated the wrapper class with `@JsonRootName`, that is always serialized with the original class name. It looks like that the annotation is totally ignored. The same happens if I use `@JsonTypeName` and `@JsonTypeInfo` (which I found in some example around).

I have written the following simple JUnit test, which proves the issue:

```
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.POJONode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class POJONodeJsonRootNameTest {

    static final String XML_PRE_PTRN = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>%s";

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    @Test
    public void shouldConvertObjectFromXmlToJson() throws IOException {

        String xml = format(XML_PRE_PTRN, "<test><name>test</name><description>test</description></test>");

        JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);

        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new TestWrapper(node));

        System.out.println(json);

        assertNotNull(json);
    }

    @JsonRootName(value = "test")
    private class TestWrapper extends POJONode {

        public TestWrapper(Object v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual result**

```
{"TestWrapper":{"name":"test","description":"test"}}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{"test":{"name":"test","description":"test"}}
```

In the pom file, I have added dependecies of `jackson-databind`, `jackson-dataformat-xml` and `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`, all version *2.12.4* (currently the latest one).

If I am doing something wrong please suggest a fix or, possibly, an alternative. Again, let me stress out, it is necessary for me to extend `POJONode` class, due to legacy code.

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Not sure if this can help you, but with jackson 2.9.9 your code works as you expected. A possible alternative is delete the json annotation and try         `String json = mapper.writer().withRootName("test").writeValueAsString(new TestWrapper(node));`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @dariosicily, I will try to downgrade to 2.9.9 then. Unfortunately the second option would not be easily applicable with the legacy code I've been working on.

Comment: You are welcome, with 2.9.9 the code works with no efforts.

Comment: I opened an issue on FasterXml issue tracker: [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3226). That might be a bug introduced in latest version. Hope they come back with a fix.

Comment: @dariosicily the downgrade worked. Actually, I figured out that it all works fine up until version 2.10.5. As I said, there must be a bug introduced after that version. I will report that to the developers as well. Thanks for your help. You can write an answer about this, so I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments to the question, [Marco Tizzano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5546673/marco-tizzano) 's code works fine up until jackson 2.10.5 version. This would suggest that after this version a regression issue had been included and appeared again in the latest jackson 2.12.4 version released in the month of July 2021. Marco Tizzano reported the issue to the developers on the FasterXml issue tracker :  the link with the complete description of the issue is [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3226).